# Install Ruby on Unix platform without root permission

Tags: unix, ruby

I'm working on a Unix platform on VNC viewer. Now I want to upgrade to Ruby version 1.9.2.

I don't have root permissions. So is there any way by which I could install Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). It gives you a Ruby installation for your own user, so you don't mess with the system Ruby.

You can install it by running the `curl` or `wget` command from the [`rbenv-installer`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer#rbenv-installer) script.

Follow the instructions to modify your shell config scripts.

Then run:

```
rbenv install 3.0.0
```

Replace `3.0.0` with the version you need to install.

And to use it globally:

```
rbenv global 3.0.0
```

Previously, I would have recommended [RVM](https://rvm.io), but I switched to `rbenv` for it breaking less and making more sense to me.